# How to improve onsite SEO if the site contain mainly picture?

Tags: keywords, meta-keywords

And design requires that we don't add texts.

The site contains only pictures. I think it needs some text. However, I do not want the text to be shown.

Should I put it on img title? Should I hide it on description? Should I use meta keywords?

What should I do?

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board. To avoid further disappointment please check our help center or alternatively use our chat channel for board, duplicate, off topic and too specific questions.

Comment: Is it too broad or too specific? Which one is right?

Comment: both... and maybe duplicate if its about increasing rankings as there are lots of questions on pro webmasters regarding SEO.

Comment: See > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52813/tackling-thin-content-on-an-images-gallery and many other subjects on sites with low content text with only images, please use the search.

Comment: I would take a look at this too:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/how-do-i-get-images-for-my-site-to-return-in-google-searches/. The accepted best answer for that has great suggestions and source links .

Comment: I would have been happy to create an answer, I don't think the question is too broad. @Sharen: use alt and title (with descriptive text, no keyword stuffing, it is illegal), but don't use hidden text (illegal) or meta tags (not taken into consideration by search engines).

Comment: Hey @JVerstry the question was closed on several reasons, as a long time member you should know that moderators by default can only check one excuse. I've amended the closure reason to be less confusing. Additionally if you want to help a user on any question that has been closed for one reason or more you could vote reopen or invite them to private chat using the Stack Private Chat system.